# Can't click button with selenium java

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I had some success prior to this using below code.

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//xpath")).click();`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='container']/div[@id='main']/div[@id='columnOne']/div[@class='ng-scope']/div[@class='content ng-scope']/div/div[@class='ng-isolate-scope']/div[@class='tab-content']/div[@class='tab-pane ng-scope active']/div[@class='ng-scope']/div[@id='uploadRequests']/div[@id='fileUploadPanel']/div[@class/span[@class='btn btn-primary']='panel-body']/div/div[@class='panel panel-default']/div[@class='panel-heading clearfix']/div[@class='pull-left']/label")).click();
```

Here is the html:

```html
<div class="panel-body">
   <div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
      <div class="pull-left">
       <label for="inputFile"><input class="hidden" type="file" name="inputFile" id="inputFile" on-change-action="addFile" multiple="">
        <span class="btn btn-primary xh-highlight"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Add</span>
       </label>
      </div>
      <div class="pull-right ng-hide" ng-show="files.length > 0"><button ng-click="removeAll()" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>Clear All</button></div>
     </div>
     <!-- ngRepeat: file in files -->
     <div class="panel-body ng-hide" ng-show="progressBar">
      <div>
       <div class="progress-striped active progress ng-isolate-scope" value="uploadProgress" type="info">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" ng-class="type &amp;&amp; 'progress-bar-' + type" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" ng-style="{width: (percent < 100 ? percent : 100) + '%'}" aria-valuetext="%" aria-labelledby="progressbar" ng-transclude="" style="width: 100%;"></div>
</div>
      </div>
      <div>
       <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="progressBar = false">Continue</button></div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

I usually try *By.className(className), By.id(id), By.name(name), By.linkText(linkText)* before By.xpath, but even here as a last resort I'm not able to click on an "Add" files button after I log onto a site.

Comment: try this code :- `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='btn btn-primary']")).click();`

Comment: try this code :- driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.btn.btn-primary")).click();

Answer (score -1):

Try to avoid of using xpath. There are very few situations, when there is no possibility to use another selectors, like css selectors or classes. Also there is not enough HTML code to find out why your xpath doesn't work. Please add more info.

PS try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='inputFile']/span[@class='btn btn-primary']")).click();
```

Comment: Can you explain, why did you wrote this? `Try to avoid of using xpath.` and the main part is you are using `xpath` locator to find the webelement., So what does that mean man??

Comment: Sure, because, when you are using xpath to find an element it takes longer to locate the element and more probably you'll get an error like author has. But the question was about xpath, thats why I wrote the suggestion to find the element using xpath, otherwise it wouldn't be an answer to the question, isn't it?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I added more html above.